# ZFS: Replace raidz1-member of a striped pool for raidz2

Tags: zfsonlinux, syntax

I have a pool (in Ubuntu 20 LTS) like this:

```
# zpool status
  pool: zpool_test
 state: ONLINE
  scan: none requested
config:

    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    zpool_test  ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz2-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdb     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdc     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdd     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sde     ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz1-1  ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdf     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdg     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdh     ONLINE       0     0     0
      sdi     ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz2-2  ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdj     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdk     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdl     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdm     ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

With creating this zpool, I made a typo, accidentally adding a raidz1 instead of raidz2. (see raidz1-1)
I reproduced the situation with this zpool_test. Create-command:

```
# zpool create zpool_test -o ashift=12 -f \
raidz2 \
 /dev/sdb \
 /dev/sdc \
 /dev/sdd \
 /dev/sde \
raidz1 \
 /dev/sdf \
 /dev/sdg \
 /dev/sdh \
 /dev/sdi \
raidz2 \
 /dev/sdj \
 /dev/sdk \
 /dev/sdl \
 /dev/sdm
```

I now want to replace this raidz1-set with a raidz2 set.
I tried it with a normal striped set; I could just use zpool replace zpool_test /dev/disk1 /dev/disk4 (for example) which were immediately the members of the stripe-set.
But now the raidz1 is the member of course (containing disks).

Feels like it is just a syntax thing, but with wild guessing I haven't been successful so far :-)
Anybody an idea?
Obviously I have 4 disks available: /dev/sdn /dev/sdo /dev/sdp /dev/sdq

Comment: Running a raidz2 over four disks is a bad idea. Stripe + Mirror RAID is more efficient and has similar failure tolerance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you have to rebuild and configure the zpool with the correct desired layout.

There isn't another option for the setup.